# cvs merge error

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv data (converted from xlsx to csv but with wordwrap, don't know how to get every xlsx-row as csv-line without wordwrap of cells) like this:

```
    1099411,wlan: Possible leakage of original sequence numbers and source address of probe request frames affecting user privacy (Applicable to Android O or later) [FW],WConnect,WLAN Embedded SW,High,AdjacentNetwork,CWE-330 Use of Insufficiently Random Values,"The original mac spoofing feature does not use the following in probe request frames: (a) randomized sequence numbers and (b) randomized source address for cfg80211 scan, vendor scan and pno scan which may affect user privacy.","Turn ON the Wi-Fi and sniff the probe requests to find out the following:
(a) incremental (non-randomized) sequence numbers and
(b) original MAC address of the device",Publicly known,None,None,"Mac randomization refers to the randomization of probe request source address and sequence numbers.
This change implements Mac randomization to randomize probe request&#39;s source MAC address and sequence number in host, vendor and pno scans to maintain / improve user&#39;s privacy.

The change requires the framework (Android O or later) to actually set this feature","wlan_framegen.c
wlan_framegen.h
wlan_mgmt_local_txrx.c
wlan_mgmt_local_txrx.h
wlan_rtt.c
wlan_rtt.h
wlan_scan.c
wlan_scan_priv.h
wlan_scan_sm.c
wlan_vdev_keepalive.c",None,None
1079713,Buffer overflow vulnerability in ioctl V4L2_CID_PRIVATE_IRIS_SET_SPURTABLE,WConnect,FMHost,High,Local,CWE-120 Buffer Copy Without Checking Size of Input ('Classic Buffer Overflow'),"If larger than expected data is set by the user in SpurTableFile.txt, during the copy_from_user call in ioctl V4L2_CID_PRIVATE_IRIS_SET_SPURTABLE, a buffer overflow in kernel memory occurs.","1. Configure /etc/fm/SpurTableFile.txt file with more than expected data.
2. Launch FM app.","CVE-2016-5345, ANDROID-32639452
Reported by Aravind Machiry, an external researcher, to ASUS, who reported it to us. We thank them for bringing this issue to our attention.","Added stricter length check before invoking copy_from_user command to avoid copying data more than allocation. If length is out of range, an error is returned.",drivers/media/radio/radio-iris.c,None,None,"https://source.codeaurora.org/patches/quic/la/.PATCH_171295_QPSIIR_367_security_patch_20161109.tar.gz

","This vulnerability is planned to be publicly disclosed on 
2016-12-05 in the Android Security Bulletin 2016 December.","After downloading the patch, use OpenSSL to decrypt the file.

Symmetric key: z}aE]X4Qx9jL(I3VGiKO 

Example command: 
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in msm-3.18.git-af9a7c8e832f4dd1d366e31b716c8f9e89bde89f.patch -out msm-3.18.git-af9a7c8e832f4dd1d366e31b716c8f9e89bde89f.patch.txt -pass 'pass:z}aE]X4Qx9jL(I3VGiKO'","APQ8009 , APQ8009W , APQ8016 , APQ8026 , APQ8037 , APQ8039 , APQ8052 , APQ8053 , APQ8056 , APQ8076 , APQ8092 , APQ8094 , APQ8096 , APQ8096AU , APQ8096SG , APQ8098 , MDM9607 , MDM9628 , MDM9640 , MDM9645 , MDM9650 , MSM8108 , MSM8208 , MSM8209 , MSM8608 , MSM8909 , MSM8909W , MSM8916 , MSM8917 , MSM8926 , MSM8928 , MSM8929 , MSM8937 , MSM8939 , MSM8952 , MSM8953 , MSM8956 , MSM8976 , MSM8976SG , MSM8992 , MSM8994 , MSM8996 , MSM8996AU , MSM8996SG , MSM8998"
731393,Heap overflow vulnerability in MSM modem causing device crash,Modem,SEC,High,AdjacentNetwork,CWE-120 Buffer Copy Without Checking Size of Input ('Classic Buffer Overflow'),"During SSL handshake, a one byte heap overflow was detected by heap integrity check and resulted in a device crash. The filled area was extended 1 Byte but the requesting heap size was not changed. On Launching GoogleMap application, a crash was observed every time.",Launch GoogleMap application.,"CVE-2016-6726 ANDROID-30775830

This issue was reported to Google by a security researcher. We thank Google for bringing this issue to our attention.",Made changes to handle SubjectAltName validation of ServerCert.,sme_ssl_shared.lib,None,None,No,None,"APQ8009, APQ8009W, APQ8016, APQ8017, APQ8037, APQ8039, APQ8052, APQ8053, APQ8056, APQ8076, APQ8084, APQ8092, APQ8094, APQ8096, APQ8096AU, APQ8096SG, APQ8098, MDM9206, MDM9225, MDM9225M, MDM9230, MDM9235M, MDM9330, MDM9607, MDM9625, MDM9625M, MDM9628, MDM9630, MDM9635M, MDM9640, MDM9645, MDM9650, MDM9655, MSM8108, MSM8208, MSM8209, MSM8608, MSM8909, MSM8909W, MSM8916, MSM8917, MSM8926, MSM8928, MSM8929, MSM8937, MSM8939, MSM8940, MSM8952, MSM8953, MSM8956, MSM8976, MSM8976SG, MSM8992, MSM8994, MSM8996, MSM8996AU, MSM8996SG, MSM8998, SDX20M"
1114793,Out of Bounds Write on the Heap when Parsing an Interrogate (Supplementary Service) Packet,Modem,MMCP,Critical,AdjacentNetwork,CWE-20 Improper Input Validation,Buffer overflow occurs if the network sends more than 5 CCBS (completion of call to busy subscriber) feature list when UE interrogated the supplementary service.,"1. Power on and register on W or G
2. UE has interrogated supplementary service
3. Network sends RELEASE_COMPLETE with CCBS info having CCBS feature list more than 5 entries (non standard-compliant value)","CVE-2017-6211
Privately reported by Matt Spisak, an external researcher.","Added checks so that buffer overflow will not occur even if Network sends the CCBS entries more than 5, processing only those that are in range.",mn_ss_processing.c,None,None,No,None,"APQ8009, APQ8009W, APQ8016, APQ8017, APQ8026, 
APQ8037, APQ8039, APQ8052, APQ8053, APQ8056, 
APQ8076, APQ8084, APQ8092, APQ8094, APQ8096, 
APQ8096AU, APQ8096SG, APQ8098, MDM6200, MDM6600, 
MDM8215, MDM8215M, MDM8615M, MDM9206, MDM9215, 
MDM9225, MDM9225M, MDM9230, MDM9235M, MDM9310, 
MDM9330, MDM9607, MDM9615, MDM9615M, MDM9625, 
MDM9625M, MDM9628, MDM9630, MDM9635M, MDM9640, 
MDM9645, MDM9655, MSM8108, MSM8110, MSM8112, 
MSM8126, MSM8208, MSM8209, MSM8210, MSM8212,
MSM8226, MSM8228, MSM8608, MSM8610, MSM8612, 
MSM8626, MSM8628, MSM8905, MSM8909, MSM8909W, 
MSM8916, MSM8917, MSM8926, MSM8928, MSM8929, 
MSM8937, MSM8939, MSM8952, MSM8953, MSM8956, 
MSM8960, MSM8976, MSM8976SG, MSM8992, MSM8994, 
MSM8996, MSM8996AU, MSM8996SG, MSM8998, QSC6155, 
QSC6165, QSC6175, QSC6185, QSC6195, QSC6270, 
QSC6295, QSC6695, QSD8250, QSD8650"
2100627,Use of Out-of-range Pointer Offset in VP9 content playback,Multimedia,Video,High,Network,CWE-823 Use of out-of-range pointer offset,"On some hardware revisions where VP9 decoding is hardware-accelerated, the frame size is not programmed correctly into the decoder hardware which can lead to an invalid memory access by the decoder.","Play VP9 content with non-mod 8 resolution, e.g. http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/interactive/html5-video-media/2017/07/05/icbm.webm","CVE-2017-11076,A-65049457. Reported by Google.",Code changes were in FW to program the byte-aligned frame dimensions to HW.,vfw_vpx_hw_ifc.c,None,None,This vulnerability is publicly known,None,"APQ8009,APQ8009W,APQ8017,APQ8037,APQ8053,APQ8096,APQ8096AU,APQ8096SG,APQ8098,MDM9640,MSM8108,MSM8208,MSM8209,MSM8608,MSM8909,MSM8909W,MSM8917,MSM8937,MSM8953,MSM8996,MSM8996AU,MSM8996SG,MSM8998,SDA845,SDM845"
1050893,Use of Uninitialized Variable while playing HEVC content using HD DMB ,Multimedia,Video,High,Local,CWE-457 Use of Uninitialized Variable,"While playing HEVC content using HD DMB, an uninitialized variable can be used leading to a kernel fault.",Play HEVC content with errors where the closest picture index in the forward or backward direction is not in the DPB frame.,Reported by a customer,The logic to handle backward reference pictures in HEVC error concealment cases is upgraded,vfw_h265_ref_list.c,None,None,This vulnerability is not publicly known,"APQ8053,APQ8096,APQ8096AU,APQ8096SG,APQ8098,MDM9640,MSM8953,MSM8996,MSM8996AU,MSM8996SG,MSM8998"
1087647,wlan: Some information elements (IEs) in probe request frame affecting user privacy (Applicable to Android O or later) [FW],WConnect,WLAN Embedded SW,High,Adjacent,CWE-200 Information Exposure,"The probe requests originated from user's phone contains the information elements which specifies the supported wifi features. This shall impact the user's privacy if someone sniffs the probe requests originated by this DUT. Hence, control the presence of which information elements is supported.",Turn ON the Wi-Fi and sniff the probe requests for information elements using which supported features can be known.,Publicly known,"IE whitelisting refers to the inclusion of selected IEs in probe request frames.
This change adds sending probe request routines, inspect which IE white listing can be controlled, if enabled, then includes only selective IEs and vendor OUIs specified in the ie bitmap and vendor oui bitmap.
The change requires the framework (Android O or later) to actually set whitelist IEs.
",wlan_batch_scan_offload.c
wlan_dev.c
wlan_extscan_bucket.c
wlan_framegen.c
wlan_framegen.h
wlan_lpi.c
wlan_network_list_offload.c
wlan_rtt.c
wlan_scan.c
wlan_scan.h
wlan_scan_sch.c
wlan_scan_sm.c
wlan_vdev_keepalive.c,None,None,This vulnerability is publicly known,"APQ8009,APQ8017,APQ8053,APQ8076,APQ8096,APQ8096AU,APQ8096SG,MDM9206,MDM9250,MDM9607,MDM9628,MDM9640,MSM8909,MSM8976,MSM8992,MSM8996,MSM8996AU,MSM8996SG,SDX20M"
1099411,wlan: Possible leakage of original sequence numbers and source address of probe request frames affecting user privacy (Applicable to Android O or later) [FW],WConnect,WLAN Embedded SW,High,Adjacent,CWE-330 Use of Insufficiently Random Values,"The original mac spoofing feature does not use the following in probe request frames: (a) randomized sequence numbers and (b) randomized source address for cfg80211 scan, vendor scan and pno scan which may affect user privacy.",Turn ON the Wi-Fi and sniff the probe requests to find out the following:
(a) incremental (non-randomized) sequence numbers and
(b) original MAC address of the device,Publicly known,"Mac randomization refers to the randomization of probe request source address and sequence numbers.
This change implements Mac randomization to randomize probe request's source MAC address and sequence number in host, vendor and pno scans to maintain / improve user's privacy.

The change requires the framework (Android O or later) to actually set this feature",wlan_framegen.c
wlan_framegen.h
wlan_mgmt_local_txrx.c
wlan_mgmt_local_txrx.h
wlan_rtt.c
wlan_rtt.h
wlan_scan.c
wlan_scan_priv.h
wlan_scan_sm.c
wlan_vdev_keepalive.c,None,None,This vulnerability is publicly known,"APQ8009,APQ8017,APQ8053,APQ8076,APQ8096,APQ8096AU,APQ8096SG,MDM9206,MDM9250,MDM9607,MDM9628,MDM9640,MSM8909,MSM8976,MSM8992,MSM8996,MSM8996AU,MSM8996SG,SDX20M"
```

If I try to merge this ith other file I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "QC_SB_AMSS_Copy.py", line 284, in <module>
    dfnew = pd.merge(df, dfold, how='left')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 53, in merge
    copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 562, in __init__
    self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 906, in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys
    **{name: self.left[name].astype(object)})
TypeError: assign() keywords must be strings
```

Normally my merge-function works fine. But with this last csv-lines I get the merge-error. Do somebody know a solution? Here is a part of my code:

```
dfold = pd.read_csv(csv_newfile, delimiter=',', header=None, engine='python', usecols=range(0, 23), error_bad_lines=False)
dfnew = pd.merge(df, dfold, how='left')
```

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]? It's hard to guess without seeing any of your code.

Comment: If there is word-wrap (with line breaks), it is not CSV any more. A simple check you could do is re-importing the thing in Excel. (By the way: was it exported using Excel's export functionality or was it exported in a home-made way, e.g. VBA?)

Comment: @tevemadar "it is not CSV any more". Why not? Escaping line breaks in `csv` works, well, maybe clumsily, but this is something I have seen many times (and there is no real standard for `csv` anyway). Suggestion: you seem to work with `pandas`; would using `csv` module to change the delimiters work?

Comment: Your file is incorrect because some fields containing line breaks were not correctly quoted. Force quoting at CSV creation time, the current file is just not useable.

Comment: I used excel export function and I am only working with pandas ....

Answer (score 0):

Pandas seems to work fine, the CSV is wrong (at least the one posted here). Initially the file reads as 31 items, while it has only 8, because (at least) 6 double-quotes are just missing:

- around the file list in report 1087647
- around the file list in report 109941
- around the "Turn ON the Wi-Fi and sniff [...] (b) original MAC address of the device" part of report 109941

Actually you can see them in the post itself: when something is in double-quotes, it has a red-ish colour, while the non-quoted are black. Just scroll down (all of them are in the lower-half of the block).

If a line break is inside a double-quoted string, Pandas properly parses it into a string like `"line1\nline2\nline3"`.

Comment: @TigerClaw unfortunately I do not know. Posted this as an answer because it was too long for a comment plus needed formatting too. I do not know Excel well enough to find out why or how it ruins some parts of the export (if that is happening at all), while the other half of the data is exported correctly, including the multi-line fields. One thing you can certainly try is manually fixing the CSV this time, and see if the merge starts working or not.

Comment: I solve this with df_qctocsv.to_csv(f, sep=',', header=None, index_label=False, index=False,quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)